# Proving that a matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ T $ be the linear operator on $ \Bbb R^3 $ which is represented by the matrix 
$$    A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6 & -3 & -2 \\
        4 & -1 & -2 \\
        10 & -5 & -3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Prove that $ T $ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Any idea.......?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-6&3&2\\-4&x+1&2\\-10&5&x+3\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$(x-6)(x^2+4x+3)-60-40-10(x-6)+12(x+3)+20(x+1)=$$

$$=x^3-2x^2-21x-18-100-10x+60+12x+36+20x+20=$$

$$=x^3-2x^2+x-2=(x-2)(x^2+1)$$

Thus, $\,A\,$ is diagonalizable over the complex $\,\Bbb C\,$...but not over the reals, say.